# Proving the surjectivity of $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have to find a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ which is

a) surjective and

b) the element $1$ of the image has $\infty$ preimages that point to it.

I understand the concept of surjectivity but am at a loss to prove that the function I found is surjective.

$$f(x) = 1$$

$$\forall y\in\mathbb{N},\exists x\in\mathbb{N}:f(x)=y$$

Would the function $f(x) = 1$ considered surjective even though it basically just maps every element of $X$ to $1$?

Comment: No $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ is not a surjective function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.  For example, there is no $x \in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) = 17$.

Comment: I might recommend a further [edit] to your post to clarify what $X,Y$ are supposed to be. I imagine the domain and codomain respectively, but you've already named those to be $\mathbb{N}$, so it's a bit unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: I edited the question @PrincessEev, I now see that I wasn’t really understanding surjectivity. I thought since 1 is in the image and has at least one preimage, the assumption holds, but I see my mistake now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not at all surjective. Every element of the codomain needs to have a preimage, an element in the domain mapping to it.

This means that there needs to be some element mapping to $1$, some element mapping to $2$, some element mapping to $3$, and so on. Possibly multiple such elements in each case, but definitely at least one. Your function, for example, has nothing mapping to $2$ (no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = 2$), so it's not surjective.

If I might proffer a suggestion, base your function on something you know to be surjective, and modify it accordingly. I for instance would start with $f(x)=x$ as a sort of "base idea", but instead map every other element to $1$, and make the function go up half as fast (to compensate for revisiting $1$ so frequently). More precisely, I would go with

$$f(x) := \begin{cases}
x/2, & x \text{ is even} \\
1, & x \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$

Note that

- $1 = f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = f(5) = f(7) = f(9) = \cdots$
- $f(4) = 2$
- $f(6) = 3$
- $f(8) = 4$
- $\vdots$

Verifying that this function is well-defined and surjective I'll leave up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I have a function that satisfies all points but I realize now that I was wrong. Your example made me understand it once and for all I think